# Cannot set artifactory repository on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, artifactory

I followed [Empower Jenkins with Artifactory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82sWH-5ooS8) video on YouTube. Basically, I added a new user to artifactory and granted it deploy permissions. Then I configured system configuration on Jenkins and tested that the configurations were right.

I created a new job and tried to set the deployment task to deploy it to artifactory. The problem is there is no repository on the dropdown.

[image]

I want to know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the job and reloading it.
 
The logic behind this behavior is to avoid a long list of repositories. Some users have hundreds of  local repositories which takes a long time to display. By entering credentials, you can display a filtered list containing only relevant repositories.
There is an open issue to add a refresh button so there will be no need to save the job prior to displaying the list.

**Update**

This issue was resolved with the release of version 2.2.3 of the plugin. For more info see [HAP-483](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-483)